# Prove or disprove that f(x,y)=((x+y)/x,x^2+y^2) is one-to-one

Tags: functions

Prove or disprove that f:DxD->DxD is one-to-one, where D={$x∈R:x>0$}

$f(x,y)=(\frac{x+y}{x},x^2+y^2)$

x and y must be positive

Also, prove or disprove that f is onto DxD.

Comment: A similar problem to this took the majority of my time in exam 3 and this problem appeared on the final.  I searched Math SE for an answer but did not find anything close enough to the problem on the exam for me to use.  There is nothing like this in the textbook.  I would appreciate it if someone took the time to answer this.

Comment: Try converting to polar coordinates is $f(r, \theta)$ 1-1?

Comment: For any $x>0$ note that $f(x,-x)=(0,2x^2)=f(-x,x)$. This proves not 1-1. It is onto, for any $(t,r)$ with $t>0$ and $r>0$ solve $t=\frac{x+y}x$ under the constraint $r=x^2+y^2$, use that $\frac{x+y}x\to\infty$ when $x\to0$, and $\frac{x+y}x\to0$ when $x\to-y$. Oops, negative $x$ are not allowed, so may proof that $f$ is not 1-1 is incorrect, and my proof of "onto" is incorrect as well, but I will leave it as it may be corrected, proving the opposite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set 1) u= (x+y)/x (=1 + (y/x) >1 SO f IS CERTAINLY NOT ONTO DxD)  and set

2)  v = x*2 + y^2   . One -one means that if (u,v) is in the range of f then (x,y) is determined uniquely by (u,v)  . Here we can solve explicitly for x and y ,Write (1) as y= x(u-1) and insert in 2) to get x^2 + x*2(u+1)^2 =v so that 
x = the positive square root of v/(1 + (u-1)^2   so y = x(u-1)  are uniquely determined . Yes ,f is 1-1 .
 The moral  is - 1-1 means in principle you can solve for x,y in terms of u,v . Onto means there are no constraints to what u,v are .Here u must be > 1 to keep y>0 .